# Qt - Don't append major version number to the end of executable/library name

Tags: qt, dll, version, filenames, naming

How can I stop Qt from renaming my DLL to `MyDLLName{MAJOR_VERSION_NUM}.dll`?

This only happens when I set the `VERSION` in my project file, but I also want to set the version. For example, if I have:

```
VERSION = 1.2.3.4
```

And my library is named `MyDll`, it will create my DLL in the debug folder as `MyDLL1.dll`. If I take the version number away, it keeps the name as I want it (`MyDLL.dll`).

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why library name gets an additional 0 in its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404774/why-library-name-gets-an-additional-0-in-its-name)

Comment: Also you can use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42269750/1536843

Answer (score 14):

Use this:

```
CONFIG += skip_target_version_ext
```

Answer (score 6):

See this answer (on SO) for why it is there:  [Why library name gets an additional 0 in its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404774/why-library-name-gets-an-additional-0-in-its-name)

You can "not-set" the version to remove it from the generated name, but are you sure you want to do that?  (It's there to avoid DLL Hell.)

The "proper-answer" is that the `LIB` template is adding the version number.

Also, note:

- `VERSION` is used to define `VER_MAJ` and `VER_MIN`
- msvc_nmake generator adds `/VERSION:major.minor` to link flags if !empty
- msvc_vcproj generate adds `/VERSION:major.minor` to link flags and `MSVCPROJ_VERSION` if !empty

You can explicitly set those yourself, or "unset" any of them.

You can explicitly remove the version number from the target name with the `TARGET_EXT` variable, for example, see:  http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_add_version_information_to_my_application

If you want to create your own plugin to decide how to generate the target name (without the version number), you can make your own plugin as described in this answer (on SO): [How to avoid having version numbers in .so file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754434/qmake-how-to-avoid-having-version-numbers-in-so-file-name)

Comment: It is usefull to be removed when using minGW + Cygwin, because generating file links from .so.1.2.3 to .so  does not work in windows.

Comment: Giving each version a new file name is not practical. The file name is explicitly referenced in the Installer builder, and when called by the EXE. Changing the source each time is too troublesome.