# Qmake appends '1' to output file name when building a dll project for VS2017

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017, qmake, vcxproj

I've come across an issue when building a VS2017 solution from a qmake .pro file, using the 'Qt Vs Tools' plugin.

When I try to indicate that my output file is to be a `.dll`, I'm met with confusing behaviours.

I have set `TEMPLATE = lib` and do not change it anywhere else in the file. From what the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-common-projects.html#building-a-library) tell me, all I should need to do is append `dll` to `CONFIG`. However, when I do so:

- Configuration type + target extension is correct (Dynamic Library / .dll)
- File name is incorrect - a '1' is appended to it. (`output_file_name` -> `output_file_name1`)

None of these errors exist if I choose to generate a `.lib` instead. I didn't notice these when building on Ubuntu 16.4, and using `CONFIG += plugin`.

My full CONFIG value at the end of the file is:
`lex yacc debug exceptions depend_includepath testcase_targets import_plugins import_qpa_plugin windows file_copies qmake_use warn_on release link_prl flat debug_and_release debug_and_release_target precompile_header autogen_precompile_source embed_manifest_dll embed_manifest_exe shared release no_plugin_manifest win32 msvc copy_dir_files c++11 debug_and_release force_debug_info dll c++11 debug_and_release force_debug_info`

Am I missing/misusing a flag? Is that behaviour intentional - if so, why is it not addressed in documentation?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Qt - Don't append major version number to the end of executable/library name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636397/qt-dont-append-major-version-number-to-the-end-of-executable-library-name). You have basically duplicated the question.